# Autogenerate primary key (Guid) Entity Framework CTP5

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-ctp5

I have a following POCO class

```
public class Account
    {
        [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]
        public string AccountId { set; get; }

        public string FirstName { set; get; }

        public string LastName { set; get; }

        public string Email { set; get; }


    }
```

I get the following exception when the database gets created

```
Identity column 'AccountId' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable.
```

Comment: Note: This also happens if you use the "reserved" identity column name `Id` in your model class, even if you have `[Key,DatabaseGenerated(...)]` on it - you have to "rename away" your identity property in your model to something else, as in this case, `AccountId`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shouldn't you have:

```
    [Key,DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid AccountId { set; get; }
```

?

Comment: Exactly...I have bymistakenly typed string...as soon as i changed it to Guid it worked....thanks

Answer (score 3):

Jeff's answer is right. Just a little tip for you. Using EF6 I wrote next configuration in order to set all fields with name "Id" and type "Guid" as identity.

```
modelBuilder.Properties<Guid>()
           .Where(info => info.Name.ToLower()== "id")
           .Configure(configuration => configuration.HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity));
```

So I don't have to write `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGenerationOption.Identity)]` everytime.

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you have to update your AccountId property from string to one of the mentioned datatypes in the exception:

int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable

Any reason why it's now a string?