# Autogenerate ID GUID datatype Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have looked at this post and tried to do it this way

[Autogenerate primary key (Guid) Entity Framework CTP5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5610794/autogenerate-primary-key-guid-entity-framework-ctp5)

```
 [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
 public Guid CompanyID { set; get; }
```

However I am still getting the error

```
Identity column 'CompanyID' must be of data type int, bigint, smallint, tinyint, or decimal or numeric with a scale of 0, and constrained to be nonnullable.
```

This is when I run Update-Database command on the package manager console.

Comment: I have a feeling that it's because I have data already in the CompanyID column whcih is why it's not letting me

Comment: Are you adding the  [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)] as part of the migration?

The answer by lightyeare here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081096/entity-framework-6-guid-as-primary-key maybe of some help.

Comment: Just tried that and it didn't work I did this:
AlterColumn("dbo.dbCompanies", "CompanyID", c => c.Guid(nullable: false, identity: true, defaultValueSql: "newsequentialid()"));

Comment: Are your existing CompanyId's already Guid's?
Just wondering as in one of your previous questions a CompanyId was  an int.
(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30244351/adding-entity-to-identity-model)

Comment: no they are not, so should I delete all entries and basically change it to guid?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to use Guid's then you'll need to change the current entries to use those as well, you can't mix datatypes :) Have you checked for any foreign key constraints, or any existing code which is expecting an int? (Not sure where you are in the application lifecycle)

Comment: There are 3 tables that depend on that primary key, so I will probably have to delete those as well.  I'll give this a try today and let you know how it goes!

Answer (score 3):

Had the same issue, the only thing helped me is dropping database to initial empty state, removing all migrations and creating a new one with proper GUID key:

1. `Update-Database -TargetMigration:0`
2. Remove all migrations
3. `Add-Migration InitialCreate`
4. `Update-Database`

I agree that this is not a best solution, but it was acceptable for me since I had started project a few hours before.